# Lipschitz property in infinite dimensional space!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In finite dimensional space, if a function $f$ is continuous differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$ then $f$ is locally Lipschitz at $x_0$. The proof for this is based on the Mean Value Theorem.

Does this assertion still hold in infinite dimensional space?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you just need Gateaux differentiability on a convex set, and you can apply the inequality $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \leq \|f'\|_\infty \|x-y\|$, where $\|f'\|_\infty$ is the least upper bound of $\|f'\|$ on the segment $[x,y]$.

Answer (score 0):

As Siminore wrote: it works the same. If $U$ is a convex neighborhood of $x_0$ in which the derivative of $f$ is bounded, then $f$ is Lipschitz in $U$. The Lipschitz condition is verified for pairs of points, and any pair of points lies on a line — thus, the infinite-dimensionality of the space does not really come into the picture. You just deal with the restriction of $f$ to a line.